# Create instance of derived abstract class in c++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, instantiation

I have got this problem and don't know how to solve it.

Suppose I have these base classes:

```
class ValueBase
{
    private:
    int base_value;

    public:
    int GetValue();
    void SetValue(int val);
    virtual ValueBase* Meet(ValueBase* const a, ValueBase* const b) = 0;
}

class NodeBase
{
    private:
    ValueBase* base_nodeValue;

    public:
    bool AddValue(int val);
}
```

and derived class:

```
class Value : public ValueBase
{
    public:
    Value* Meet(ValueBase* a, ValueBase* b) override;
}
```

Is there a way to create instance of class `Value` in method `AddValue` in class `NodeBase`? I know that I should probably make `AddValue` pure virtual and implement it in derived class of `NodeBase`, but is there possibility to do it without this option? Can I use e.g. template method or maybe a callback to method in `Value` that would construct that object? Or is it just too evil to do it?

EDITED:
I don't have access to derived class `Value` in class `NodeBase`

Comment: `bool AddValue(int val) { base_nodeValue = new Value; }` boom, done.

Comment: Right, I missed out one catch, see edit please.

Comment: Can't you forward-declare `Value`, or include the right header in order to use it in `NodeBase`?

Comment: @JonathanPotter put this as an answer so it can be accepted

Comment: So your edited question is "how do I create an instance of a class that I know nothing about?" ... obviously you can't. You either need to know about the class, or call some function that knows about it.

Comment: The title of the question is wrong and misleading, it suggests you want to create an instance of an abstract class, which is of course impossible. The fact you want to create an instance of a class derived _from_ an abstract class is irrelevant, you can just say "create instance of derived class" because that's what you're trying to do and it makes no difference whether the base is abstract or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no approach without changing class definitions. However, there are many approaches that involve changing class definitions, depending on what you are "allowed" to use.

A. Make `AddValue()` templated on the object type it should create:

```
 class NodeBase
 {
    private:
    ValueBase* base_nodeValue;

    public:
    template<class ValueType>
    bool AddValue(int val) { base_nodeValue = new ValueType; }
 }

 ...
 // other code that has access to Value
 node.AddValue<Value>(10);
```

B. Create function that creates `Value` (forwarding any arguments to constructor if needed`) and pass it as an argument to`AddValue`:

```
 // might need to adapt syntax
 class NodeBase
 {
    private:
    ValueBase* base_nodeValue;

    public:
    bool AddValue(int val, ValueBase* (*creator)()) { base_nodeValue = (*creator)(); }
 }

 ...
 // other code that has access to Value
 ValueBase* valueCreator() { return new Value; }
 ...
 node.AddValue(10, valueCreator);
```

(May use a functor or a lambda here as well)

C. You can create a function in `ValueBase` that returns `Value*`.

```
class ValueBase
{
    public:
    static ValueBase* createValue();
};

class NodeBase
{
    private:
    ValueBase* base_nodeValue;

    public:
    bool AddValue(int val) { base_nodeValue = ValueBase::createValue(); }
};

// in a separate cpp
ValueBase* ValueBase::createValue() { return new Value; }
```

This is in fact similar to a factory approach: you can have `createValue()` accept a parameter and create different `ValueBase`s depending on it. Having `ValueBase` store some pointer to creator function, you can have it not know about `Value` at all, just initialize that pointer at some other place, like you can register a subclass in a factory table in base class.

Comment: Thank you, really great answer for me :) I ended up with template method, and with some `static_assert` it works pretty nice

Answer (score 5):

Add a creation member function:

```
class ValueBase
{
public:
    virtual ValueBase * create() = 0;
    // ...
};
```

Then in `NodeBase` you can use `base_nodeValue->create()`.

Derived classes implement it:

```
class Value : public ValueBase
{
    Value * create() override { return new Value; }
};
```

The more common form of this pattern is a *clone* function, though, which does not produce a default-constructed object of the same type, but a *copy*:

```
Derived * clone() override { return new Derived(*this); }
```

Comment: That doesn't solve anything.  With that approach, you need an object of the correct derived type in order to create an object of the correct derived type.  The OP clearly wants to create one without already having one.

Comment: @KerrekSB, it may be NULL or whatever, as I read the question

Comment: @JSF, I don't think that is "clearly" the case at all. The OP says "maybe a callback to method in `Value`"  which pretty strongly suggests that having an object to call that method on is a valid consideration.